# Error when exporting from SAS to Excel - comma problem

Tags: excel, sas

so I have a code like this, when this executes

```
 data t4;
    put new_EMPLID $2000.;
    do until(last.CRSE_ID);
    set t3;
    by CRSE_ID notsorted;
      new_EMPLID = catx(',',new_EMPLID,compress(EMPLID));
    END;
    drop EMPLID;
    run;
```

output on SAS is

[image]

THEN "View in Excel"

[image]

I want to show LIKE THIS "2234944,2330002" exactly like output on SAS

Why excel is changing like pic? Does anybody know how to fix this issue???

I know , is cauing issue, when I changed to 'x', it worked on excel.

Comment: That 000025 is being stored as a number, so the leading zeroes are stripped. I'm not familiar with SAS at all but you need to store/import that as text, not a number.

Comment: How are you getting the data into Excel?

Comment: I suggest exporting your data in String formats, that way you can define the precision you wish. For documenation see: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000199377.htm

Comment: Do NOT let Excel automatically open a CSV file. Always use the text import utility so that you can control how it interprets the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What operating system, SAS version and Excel version and bittiness of each ?

What code did you submit ?

This sample code with `Proc EXPORT` exhibits no issues in Windows 10, SAS 9.4M4 and Excel 2016 64-bit.

If a `courseId` has only one attendee, or the if commas could be misinterpreted by Excel they will be :).  Your language settings can also have influence the Excel rendering.

```
data have; input
courseId employeeId; datalines;
1 2234944
1 2330002
1 1975365
1 2244221
2 1122334
2 2233445
2 3344551
run;

data want;
  do until (last.courseId);
    set have;
    by courseId;
    length attendeeList $2000;
    attendeeList = catx(',',attendeeList,employeeId);
  end;
  drop employeeId;
run;

proc export data=want dbms=excel replace file='c:\temp\course_attendence.xlsx';
run;
```